# What the difference between bindParam and execute(array)?

Tags: php, pdo

```
$stmt = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE login = ? AND md5pass = ?");
#$stmt->bindParam(1, $login, PDO::PARAM_INT);
#$stmt->bindParam(2, $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute(array($login,$pass));
$res = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Which way is better to transfer variables to prepeared statment bindParam or execute(array)? Both working but what is differense? Only PDO::PARAM checking? For SELECT I think array would be enough and for INSERT I sould use the bindParam. Am I right? Thanks to all. Just learning =)

Comment: You have answered your question yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDO bindParam vs. execute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392424/pdo-bindparam-vs-execute)

Answer (score 4):

With `bindParam` you can add the datatype and also important with bind param you are binding the variables [**by reference**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).