# Omitting bindParam with PDO is safe?

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo, sql-injection

I want to know if the use of bindParam is mandatory to prevent SQL injection using PDO and MYSQL.

Example:

```
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$cryptpass=hashFunction($password);
$sth=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,password) VALUES(?,?)");
$sth->execute(array($username,$cryptpass));
```

Is it a safe and proper way to write this code? Omitting bindParam makes shorter code.

Comment: check out this answer for detailed info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8265319/716691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still binding the values to a prepared statement. You are doing the same thing as if you were using the `bindParam` function. So the answer is yes it is just as safe. `bindParam` just allows for more functionality than simply binding with the `execute` function for example:

```
$sth=$dbh->prepare("Select * from users where status=:v1");
$sth->bindParam(':v1',1,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
```

This allows you to specify the `data_type` by default with `execute` everything is sent as a string. Also you can look at the answer to this similar question: [PDO bindParam vs. execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392424/pdo-bindparam-vs-execute)

Answer (score 1):

All that matters is that you use parameters rather than substituting directly into the query string. It doesn't matter whether you bind the parameters with `bindParam` or with an array argument to `execute`, they're equivalent.