# are my conclusion correct about pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**One:** If I use `bindParam();`, Then `execute();` will has no arguments. But if I use a array instead of `bindParam();` then `execute();` will has argument. something like this:

```
// one
$queryResults->bindParam(1,$test);
$queryResults->execute();

// two
$params = array($mfg, $price);
$queryResults->execute($params);
```

Is it right ? Yes or No ?

---

**Two:** I use `prepare($query);` for prevent of malicious code.

Is it right ? Yes or No ?

---

**Three:** `fetchAll();` is faster than `fetch();`, but it needs more memory.

Is it right ? Yes or No ?

---

**Four:** Using `::` codes are optional. for example: `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and `fetchAll();` are the same.

Is it right ? Yes or No ?

---

**Five:** I can't use unamed parameters in `union`, I have to use named parameters.

Is it right ? Yes or No ?

---

**Six:** Using `try {} catch(){}` is for the ease of catching and handling errors, using `try {}` is not mandatory.

Is it right ? Yes or No ?

---

**Seven:**

*(part one)* In PDO, If the variable does not exist, I can use `query();` and `exec();`, But when I have a variable, I should use `prepare();`. Is it right ? Yes or No ?

*(part two)* Both of these are identical. Is it right ? Yes or No ?

```
$db->query('SELECT * FROM table');
$db->exec('SELECT * FROM table');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One**: Yes, you are right. If you pass an array as a parameter to the `execute` method, then it will handle it as a bound parameter, and will consider it as a string (`PDO::PARAM_STR`).

**Two**: Yes, but you have to use it together with either `bindParam()`, `bindValue()`, or a parameterized `execute()`. You have to make sure, that you escape all the data, which has ever came from a user (such as a form post, or query string).

**Three**: Yes, according to [>this<](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2771563/3686961) Stackoverflow answer, it is just as you've described it.

**Four**: Yes, and no: yes, because it's optional (they are just constant integer values). No, `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` is not the same as `fetchAll()`. If you use the option parameter when you instantiate the PDO class, then you can change the default fetch mode to use with `fetchAll()`. For example:

```
$params = array(
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE    => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $dbname, $user, $pwd, $params);
```

You can also use the `setAttribute()` method on an existing instance to set the default fetch mode in a quite similar way:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The results are the same. Any subsequent `fetch()` or `fetchAll()` calls without a parameter will use the fetch mode you've set, or until the instance is alive.

The default fetch mode is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`, which returns an array with both associative indexes, and zero-started numerical indexes, such as the example below:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [id] => 675
      [0] => 675
      [some_value] => foo
      [1] => foo
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
      [id] => 681
      [0] => 681
      [some_value] => bar
      [1] => bar
    )
)
```

**Five**: I'm not quite sure what do you mean. It is possible to use unnamed parameters in PDO, but if you pass an associative array to `execute()`, then it will show you an error. The way to get around that, is to call `array_values()` on your array, when you're passing it to `execute()`. Example:

```
$parameters = array(
  "id"          => 123,
  "some_value"  => "foo"
);
$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = ? AND some_value = ?");
$db->execute(array_values($parameters));
```

For `union` operator *(and similar items)* you should use named parameters only. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730203/union-select-in-pdo-not-working)

**Six**: Using try-catch is completely optional, and it depends on your implementation and error-handling preference. I prefer using exceptions with try-catch, but you can use warnings or silent error codes, as described at the relevant section of the PDO::SetAttribute documentation [>here<](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php).

These can be set up using either the option parameter during PDO instantiation, or using the `setAttribute()` method on an existing PDO instance. Example:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
/*
  PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION can be replaced with either
  PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT or PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING
*/
```

If something's not clear, or you think I haven't provided a thorough answer on that part, then please let me know, and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for all. just I have a question about four. In fact when I use `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`, I'm changing default of fetching, right ? If I use just `fetchAll();`, It using of it's default, right ?! Now what is default of fetching in PDO ? and when I change it, How long is changed ?

Comment: The default fetch mode is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` and changing the fetch mode lasts until the instance is alive. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: I edited my question and  added part of *seven*, please check out ... Thanks buddy